# Chatter rest api Response - Comments Limit in a Conversation (feed-elements)

Tags: rest-api, chatter

As a customer portal user, using chatter rest api when I try to retrieve the comments on a feed. I only get the last three comments. I tried with the parameter elementsPerBundle and no luck

{Salesforce instance url}/AC/services/data/v40.0/connect/communities/0DB9E00000000Ka/chatter/feeds/record/0F99E00000007WYSAY/feed-elements?elementsPerBundle=10&recentComment​Count=10

In the response I only get three 
comments

```
 "body": {
                                "isRichText": true,

                                "text": "Voici ma réponse\n"
                            },
 "body": {
                                "isRichText": false,
                                "text": "Encore une question"
                            },
 "body": {
                                "isRichText": true,

                                "text": "Voici ma nouvelle réponse !\n"
                            },
```

Comments in the chatter

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time on this issue, I found the answer to this iss

`{Salesforce instance url}/{Community Name}/services/data/v40.0/connect/communities/{CommunityId}/chatter/feed-elements/{FeedId}/capabilities/comments/items?elementsPerBundle=10`

will give the complete list(10) of the comments.